# When we encrypt-then-MAC, how do we defend the 2 parts?

Tags: encryption, mac

When we encrypt-then-MAC (which is the recommended case), do we send both in the same package? Both can be modified along the way, isn't it? how do we defend the 2 parts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When we encrypt-then-MAC (which is the recommended case), do we send both in the same package?

Yes

> Both can be modified along the way, isn't it?

Yes, but not without the MAC check failing.

> how do we defend the 2 parts?

You don't need to do anything else. The MAC is the protection.